# Example 4.2 of Griffiths introduction to electrodynamics

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

So i was doing the chapter electric fields in matter and in example 4.2 ,the author asks to find electric field due to uniformly polarized sphere of radius R. So i think there is no free charge hence D=0 . Plugging into

D=P+eE , i get E=-(P/e) where e= permittivity of free space.
But by using conventional method by evaluating bound charges the answer is E= -(P/3e).
Why is it so? Can anybody expalin?

Comment: Could you show your work in detail?

Comment: There was a mistak actually ..i just wrote charged instead of polarized....actually it is a uniformly polarized sphere

Comment: You may find PhysicsPages useful? http://physicspages.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so because you are using the wrong $E$. 
In the equation: 
$D =  \varepsilon_0E + P$.
The electric field, $E$ is the total electric field i.e. the applied field plus the electric field polarization $P$ produces which in itself is due to the applied field in the first place. This process just continues.

Where as in the example 4.2 you are calculating the field "inside" due to the polarization $P$ only.

[image]